# Setting up multiple displays on a MacBook Pro as a single “giga-monitor.”

Tags: display, fullscreen

I have 2 extra monitors on my MacBook Pro. They are positioned like this:

[image]

I would like to use monitors 1 and 2 as a single giga-monitor.   Ideally I would like that VMWare Fusion would recognize them both as independent monitors and use only them, leaving the MacBook Pro retina display clear for other uses.

Comment: If you open Displays Preference and drag the monitors in the arrangement you have, what is wrong with using all three?

Comment: @bmike i can't full screen a app to use both 1 and 2...